# Reactjs+Redux: Retrieve this.props value after onClick async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working my way learning some react+redux-thunk and I've put together a simple form that hits an API and retrieves some jokes. My core component and code:

**containers/AsyncApp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import SearchJokes from '../components/SearchJokes';
import Jokes from '../components/Jokes';
import {fetchJokes} from '../actions';

class AsyncApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
      this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
      this.state = {searchText: ''};
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //const {searchText} = this.props;
        console.log('button clicked ' + this.state.searchText);
        this.props.fetchJokes(this.state.searchText);
    }

    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            searchText: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    render(){
        const { jokes, isFetching } = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                <SearchJokes
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    onChange={this.handleInput}
                    searchText={this.state.searchText}
                />
                {jokes ? (<Jokes jokes={jokes}/>) : (<div></div>)}

            </div>
        )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        jokes: state.items
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return{
        fetchJokes: bindActionCreators(fetchJokes, dispatch)
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AsyncApp)
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export const REQUEST_JOKES = 'REQUEST_JOKES'
export const RECEIVE_JOKES = 'RECEIVE_JOKES'


function requestJokes(term) {
    return {
      type: REQUEST_JOKES,
      term
    }
  }

  function receiveJokes(term, json) {
    return {
      type: RECEIVE_JOKES,
      term,
      jokes: json.results.map(joke => joke)

    }
  }

  export function fetchJokes(term) {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(requestJokes(term))
      return fetch(`https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=${term}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
      }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receiveJokes(term, json)))
    }
  }
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  REQUEST_JOKES,
  RECEIVE_JOKES
} from '../actions'


function jokesBySearch(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case REQUEST_JOKES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isFetching: true, items: []})
        case RECEIVE_JOKES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching: false,
                items: action.jokes,
            })
        default:
            return state
    }

}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    jokesBySearch,
  })

  export default rootReducer
```

The form component works, and I can see the json array returned as part of the action. But the value of this.props.jokes is empty or undefined in the console.log and I'm wondering how to populate it once the results from the API call are returned.

[image: Json results]

Comment: I think `items: state.jokes` should be `jokes: state.items`

Comment: @Stopee updated the mapStateToProps which makes sense. But this.props.jokes is always undefined in the console.log obviously when it it renders the component there's no jokes list.

Comment: try `jokes: state.jokesBySearch.items`

Comment: @Stopee thanks but I'll pass on that..

Comment: @moti-korets that worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems in this code.
First you don't need to use `combineReducers` when you only have one reducer. Just keep it simple and add complexity only when absolutely necessary. Instead of `combineReducers`

```
export default jokesBySearch
```

If you do use `combineReducers` be mindful how it affects your state.
Second there is no need to use `bindactioncreators` here, just dispatch the action (and don't forget to pass the `term`).

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return{
        fetchJokes: (term) => dispatch(fetchJokes(term))
    }
}
```

See here when you need to use [bindactioncreators](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators) (pretty rare use case)
In general good way to lear a library like redux is just use the core functionality until you encounter problem and only then add complexity.